# for loop code block

Tags: python, for-loop

I was reading the tutorial about python [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and was wondering that if the for loop does not have a block like this {}, how would we know which block of code is in the for loop. Are we going to have to read it base on the indentation of the code? Or did I miss something fundamental about python? And while I was trying out some python code in notepad++ when I was in the for loop and create a new line in the middle of my code it for some reason made the line of code and everything above it a block of code while everything else below something different. Again am I missing something? I hope it's not bad programming practice.

Comment: Did you read the first chapter of that tutorial? It's all about indentation.

Comment: @RohitJain no I skipped it and went straight to chapter 2 the interpreter. I'll go back then.

Comment: @JackThor Yeah, it's not just there for style. It's syntax in python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python runs everything on indentation.  The indentation level is how it knows what goes with what.

For example, this works:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

But this blows up with an `IndentationError`:

```
for i in range(10):
print i
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation):

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
>   line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
>   turn is used to determine the **grouping of statements**.

Comment: but if I where to do add a line of code to your code like this `for i in range(10);

Comment: @JackThor indentation *is* your braces. If you want to add a line in the `for` loop, have it indented the same level as the `print i`. After the `for` loop? Back to normal. Want another scope inside something already indented? Indent again. (And a word of advice, use spaces, or at least have your editor convert tabs to spaces.) If you look at sample Python code, this should become clear quite quickly.

Comment: @JackThor We use `pass` for empty compound statements: `for i in range(10):pass`

Comment: @rogaos That explained a lot. I was using tab and it was blocking the code, but if I use space it does not. thanks.